# Best way to handle complex data sent to tornado by ajax

Tags: python, ajax, tornado

This is a design question, not a code question. Title sucks, the problem isn't very describable in a few words.

I have a user database (mongodb). I built a front-end table in javascript that allows admin to see all users, edit their information, add new ones and delete them. All changes are stored in a javascript object until the admin clicks a Save button, then they are ajaxed to the server. The object looks like this:

```
{
    "new": [<ids of new users>],
    "deleted": [<ids to be deleted from database>],
    "edited": {<edited fields of existing users and all fields of new users>}
}
```

I need to send this to the server and write changes into the database. There are multiple ways to do this.

1. I send the whole object to the server, where it will be handled by one RequestHandler. I need to also have separate handlers to handle the separate "add", "delete" and "edit" operations, because they will be needed elsewhere, so I put the actual functionality into functions that can be called from more handlers so I don't repeat myself too much.
2. I send three ajax requests for new, deleted and edited. In this case, new would carry the data, not only the ids. Each is handled by the separate handler. This is easier for backend, because the one big handler from option 1 doesn't have to exist, but I don't know if it is a good idea to make multiple ajax requests like this.
3. I ajax the one big object to one handler and then using HTTPClient I send requests from the handler to the separate handlers to do their thing. Saves ajax requests and the backend implementations are a bit cleaner, but the actual server side request sending seems dirty to me.
4. Another way I don't see.

What do you think?

Comment: Maybe this isn’t what you want, but have you considered saving each record as it is added/edited/removed?  From your options, I like 1 best.  Only one outgoing request and then the backend can delegate the actions to different functions.  There might be drawbacks I’m failing to foresee though but you can always refactor that if you hit one.  I think the “RESTiest” way of doing this would be to update each record as it is changed (or at least send one request per record), but I could be wrong.

Comment: I want the admin to be able to see and reverse the changes they are making. If I sent every change to the server immediately, I'd have to keep state on the server, which seems more bothersome to me than this way. Thanks for your opinion, appreciate it.